# PDF does not download in any browser on a specific workstation

Tags: website, pdf

I am trying to resolve an issue where I have a windows 8 (v6.3) machine on which I cannot download documents from a specific financial institution's website.

On a certain financial website (that requires a login) it allows the user to download statements.

On other workstations, in multiple browsers, you can login, click the download link, it gives you a spinning ajax wheel, and then downloads it or asks where you want to download it, depending on the browser.

On this one workstation though, in IE11, chrome 47.0.2526.106 m, and firefox 43.03, when you click to download, the ajax wheel spins and then nothing happens.  No error, no download, nothing.

PDF downloads/display in browser works fine on other sites that I've tested from this system.

We've rebooted, installed java, uninstalled java, compared IE settings to another workstation.

I'm confounded.

Ideas?

(also going to send an email to the financial institution to see if they've heard of the issue)

Comment: Is Adobe Reader installed on that workstation ?

Comment: How about you get the direct URL to that file from a different computer and try on this one. You mention ajax script before download begins, is there anything that could block it ? Web security module in Cisco AnyConnect software bugged me for days a while ago.